# How can I change the Y-axis figures into percentages in a barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How can we change y axis to percent like the figure? I can change y axis range but I can't make it to percent.
[image]

Answer (score 350):

Use:

```
+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Or, to specify formatting parameters for the percent:

```
+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

(the command `labels = percent` is obsolete since version 2.2.1 of ggplot2)

Comment: I liked that you don't have to type `library(scales)` for this.

Comment: And the reason `scales::percent(accuracy = 1)` does not work is because the `*_format()` versions create a function instead of...whatever `percent()` alone creates, is that correct?

Answer (score 104):

In principle, you can pass any reformatting function to the `labels` parameter:

```
+ scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100, "%")) # Multiply by 100 & add %
```

Or

```
+ scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) # Add percent sign
```

---

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(x=seq(0,1,0.1), y=seq(0,1,0.1))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100, "%"))
```

Comment: +1 for no external dependency. I know that since Hadley is the author of both ggplot2 and scales, it shouldn't really matter—but this solution is still appreciated.

Answer (score 52):

`ggplot2` and `scales` packages can do that:

```
y <- c(12, 20)/100
x <- c(1, 2)

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
myplot <- qplot(as.factor(x), y, geom="bar")
myplot + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

---

It seems like the `stat()` option has been taken off, causing the error message. Try this:

```
library(scales)

myplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + 
          geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
          scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)

myplot
```

Answer (score 6):

Borrowed from @Deena above, that function modification for labels is more versatile than you might have thought.  For example, I had a ggplot where the denominator of counted variables was 140.  I used her example thus:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(round(x/140*100,1), "%"), breaks = seq(0, 140, 35))
```

This allowed me to get my percentages on the 140 denominator, and then break the scale at 25% increments rather than the weird numbers it defaulted to.  The key here is that the scale breaks are still set by the original count, not by your percentages.  Therefore the breaks must be from zero to the denominator value, with the third argument in "breaks" being the denominator divided by however many label breaks you want (e.g. 140 * 0.25 = 35).

Comment: If I was repeating this chart several times but the denominator changes each time, how could I change the above coding so that I wouldn't have to manually look up the denominator for each chart?