# Change the scale of x axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot bar and don't know how to change the scale of the x axis. At the moment it looks like on the image below. However I'd like to reorder the scale of the x axis so that 21% bar is higher than the 7% bar. How could I get the % to the axis? Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
df= data.frame("number" = c(7,21), "name" = c("x","y"))
df
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=number)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "blue") + xlab("Title") + ylab("Title") + 
  ggtitle("Title")
```

Comment: Can you post your code? it's not clear why the 7% is higher at the moment so not easy to help you change it

Comment: I am guessing it is reading those values as strings, if you convert that column to numeric and use ggplot to add the `%` to the axis labels it will fix things on your Y axis

Comment: I added some code above. I used the  "percent" function, which is why I got numbers in percent. I will try it with numerics. How could I get the % to the axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I am able to duplicate the original plot is, as @sconfluentus noted, for the 7% and 21% to be character strings. As an aside the data frame column names need not be quoted.

```
df= data.frame(number = c('7%','21%'), name = c("x","y"))
 df
 ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=number)) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "blue") + xlab("Title") + ylab("Title") + 
   ggtitle("Title")
```

[image]

Changing the numbers to `c(0.07, 0.21)` and adding, as @Mohanasundaram noted, `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)` corrects the situation:
[image]

To be pedantic using `breaks = c(0.07, 0.21)` creates nearly an exact duplicate. See also here.[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433798/how-can-i-change-the-y-axis-figures-into-percentages-in-a-barplot)
Hope this is helpful.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
df= data.frame(number = c(0.07,0.21), name = c("KG","MS"))
df
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=number)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "blue") + xlab("Title") + ylab("Title") + 
  ggtitle("Title") + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,  breaks = c(.07, .21)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `prop.table` function to in y variable in the geom plot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=100*prop.table(number))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "blue") + 
  xlab("Stichprobe") + ylab("Paketmenge absolut") + 
  ggtitle("Menge total")
```

[image]

If you want to have the character, % in the y axis, you can add `scale_y_continuous` to the plot as below:

```
library(scales)

ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=prop.table(number))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "blue") + 
  xlab("Stichprobe") + ylab("Paketmenge absolut") + 
  ggtitle("Menge total") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

[image]