# ggplot, facets, and scale labelling

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am producing a facet chart like this

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(scales)
})

set.seed(123456)
test_df <-
  tibble(t=1:10,
         x=100+runif(10,-10,10),
         y=10+runif(10,-4,4),
         p=y/x)

test_df |>
  pivot_longer(cols=x:p,
               names_to = "var",
               values_to = "value") |>
  mutate(var=factor(var,levels=c("x","y","p"))) ->
test_df_long

test_df_long |>
  ggplot(aes(x=t,y=value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,NA)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(var),ncol=1,
             scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

I would like to change the formatting of the labels for the p facet to percent.

I have not found a way to use different labelling functions to different facets.

Can it be done?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [`facetscales`](https://github.com/zeehio/facetscales)? It seems that it can be done.

Comment: Does this address your question: [How can I change the Y-axis figures into percentages in a barplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433798/how-can-i-change-the-y-axis-figures-into-percentages-in-a-barplot). If so, then this question is a duplicate. In short, `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the Y-axis figures into percentages in a barplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433798/how-can-i-change-the-y-axis-figures-into-percentages-in-a-barplot)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales()` to control position scales of individual facets. If you just need to adjust a single scale, you could use the [formula notation](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#formula-notation) as below. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x)

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(scales)
})

set.seed(123456)
test_df <-
  tibble(t=1:10,
         x=100+runif(10,-10,10),
         y=10+runif(10,-4,4),
         p=y/x)

test_df |>
  pivot_longer(cols=x:p,
               names_to = "var",
               values_to = "value") |>
  mutate(var=factor(var,levels=c("x","y","p"))) ->
  test_df_long

test_df_long |>
  ggplot(aes(x=t,y=value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,NA)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(var),ncol=1,
             scales = "free_y") +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    y = var == "p" ~ scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `facetscales` like this:

```
devtools::install_github("zeehio/facetscales")
library(facetscales)

scales_y <- list(
  x = scale_y_continuous(),
  y = scale_y_continuous(),
  p = scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
)

test_df_long |>
  ggplot(aes(x=t,y=value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,NA)) +
  facet_grid_sc(rows = vars(var), scales = list(y = scales_y))
```

Output:

[image]